# Azure error on deploying a Nextjs app on azure platform

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-web-app-service

Please refer to the github error.

### Error reported:

https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/1148

### Azure Project deployment log:

https://github.com/BlockchainDeveloper009/KrumpKings-webapp-thirdweb/actions/runs/4813483408/jobs/8570062624

### Error log:

```
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)


Preparing output...

Copying files to destination directory '/bin/staticsites/2f9196ac-4c8b-4fa7-8362-1308441ee5b3-swa-oryx/app'...
Done in 9 sec(s).

Removing existing manifest file
Creating a manifest file...
Manifest file created.
Copying .ostype to manifest output directory.

Done in 108 sec(s).


---End of Oryx build logs---
Finished building app with Oryx
An unknown exception has occurred

For further information, please visit the Azure Static Web Apps documentation at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/
If you believe this behavior is unexpected, please raise a GitHub issue at https://github.com/azure/static-web-apps/issues/
Exiting
```

### Original error:

"Error reported:
https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/1148

Azure Project deployment log:

https://github.com/BlockchainDeveloper009/KrumpKings-webapp-thirdweb/actions/runs/4813483408/jobs/8570062624
"

I fixed above error, and then started getting "unknown error"

I dont know how to approach this problem. Can anyone help me to start analyzing this error.

am a newbie to azure & cloud.

Answer (score 0):

> getting 'unknown error'

*Unknown error* while deploying an application could be because of various reasons:

- Incorrect configuration settings, missing dependencies, or issues with the deployment process.
- Check the logs for detailed information on the error to fix the issue.
- Ensure that all the required dependencies are installed and configured correctly.
- And try redeploying the application and check if the issue persists.
  Refer to [doc](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/35402) to know how to check github logs.

---

I have created a sample nextjs application and deployed to Azure through github.

**Workflow file:**

```
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy

# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - pravnextjsapp

on:

push:

branches:

- main

workflow_dispatch:

jobs:

build:

runs-on: windows-latest

steps:

- uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Set up Node.js version

uses: actions/setup-node@v1

with:

node-version: '18.x'

- name: npm install, build, and test

run: |

npm install

npm run build --if-present

npm run test --if-present

- name: Upload artifact for deployment job

uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2

with:

name: node-app

path: .

deploy:

runs-on: ubuntu-latest

needs: build

environment:

name: 'Production'

url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

steps:

- name: Download artifact from build job

uses: actions/download-artifact@v2

with:

name: node-app

- name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'

uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2

id: deploy-to-webapp

with:

app-name: 'pravnextjsapp'

slot-name: 'Production'

publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX }}

package: .
```

**Github:**
[image]

**Portal:**
[image]